# In Java Swing, how can I use JSliders to set x and y values for a shape?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a GUI that uses 2 JSliders; 1 vertical and 1 horizontal. I want them to return the x and y value respectively. I was able to get the x and y values, I just can't figure out how to use them so I can draw a circle.

```
    import javax.swing.JSlider;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        private javax.swing.JPanel canvas;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> colorBox;
        private javax.swing.JSlider horizontalSlider, verticalSlider;
        private javax.swing.JButton state;
        public MyFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }
        private void initComponents() {
    
            canvas = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            horizontalSlider = new javax.swing.JSlider();
            verticalSlider = new javax.swing.JSlider();
            colorBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
            state = new javax.swing.JButton();
            int diameter = 30;
            Color color;
    
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            canvas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(250, 250, 250));
    
            javax.swing.GroupLayout canvasLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(canvas);
            canvas.setLayout(canvasLayout);
            canvasLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    canvasLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            canvasLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                    canvasLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
    
            horizontalSlider.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
                public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                    horizontalSliderStateChanged(evt);
                }
            });
    
            verticalSlider.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSlider.VERTICAL);
            verticalSlider.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
                public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                    verticalSliderStateChanged(evt);
                }
            });
    
            colorBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green" }));
    
            state.setText("Show");
            state.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    stateActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    
        

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                                .addComponent(verticalSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(horizontalSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(canvas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(colorBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 92, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(state, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(verticalSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 475, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(canvas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(horizontalSlider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(colorBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(state))
                                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

pack();

}// </editor-fold>

                        
    
        private void stateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }
    
        public void horizontalSliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            horizontalSlider = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
            int coordinateX = horizontalSlider.getValue();
            System.out.println("X: " + coordinateX);
        }
    
        public void verticalSliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            verticalSlider = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
            int coordinateY = verticalSlider.getValue();
            System.out.println("Y: " + coordinateY);
        }
    
        private void colorBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt,Color color) {
            if(colorBox.getSelectedItem() == "Red") {
                color = Color.RED;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.fillOval(horizontalSlider.getValue(),verticalSlider.getValue(),30, 30);
            //g.setColor(color.getColor);
        }
    
    }
```

I don't have anything more to ask or say about my question, I just can't submit this question because there is more code than not.
So here is another question... How could I use a JComboBox to change the color of the circle based on what color is selected?

Comment: First you need to learn how to do custom painting. Then you can add logic to use the combo box and sliders. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a couple of examples.

Comment: There's actually quite a lot to this - back in the day I built an MVC AreaManager (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/) you might want to check out, but in any case, you'll probably want a Model for your Shapes, a view for displaying them, and a Controller for clicking on and otherwise manipulating them.

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

Using a GUI builder creates a code mess that's hard to expand and hard to maintain.  It's a lot easier, in the long run, to learn how to use Swing effectively without using a GUI builder. Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I couldn't get your code to run in my IDE, so I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image: JSlider Example]

The top line displays the circle center point and allows you to select a color.  The two `JSliders` allow you to select the center point x and the center point y of the circle.  The scale goes from 0 to width and height, respectively.  The code keeps you from selecting a center point outside the bounds of the drawing `JPanel`.

Since the y value `JSlider` has the minimum value on the bottom, I inverted the y value when drawing the circle.  In other words, instead of the normal y values increasing as you draw downward, the y values increase as you draw upward.

The `JSliders` don't precisely correspond with the drawing JPanel.  Since this is an example, I wasn't too worried about the visual discrepancy.

If you maximize the GUI or change the size of the GUI, the scales of the `JSliders` change accordingly.  If your circle is outside the new dimension of the drawing JPanel, the center point is changed so the circle is inside the new dimension.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

Generally, you create the model first.  The model consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  The view is your `JFrame` and `JPanels`.  The controllers are each individual Swing listener.

For this `JSlider` example, I created two model classes, two view classes, and four controller classes.  Since all the controller classes are small, I made them anonymous classes.

This application turned out to be fairly complex.  It's going to require a good bit of explanation.

### Model

For this `JSlider` example, I created two model classes, `JSliderExampleModel` and `ColorModel`.

`JSliderExampleModel` is the main model class.  It holds an array of `ColorModels`, the drawing `JPanel` dimension, and the center point and radius of the circle.  The array of `ColorModels` is for the `JComboBox`.  The radius is in the model because we need the value to keep the `JSlider` values from going outside the bounds of the drawing `JPanel`.

The `ColorModel` class holds a `String` color name and a `Color` color.  This allows us to display the color name in the `JComboBox` while having the actual `Color` for filling in the circle in the drawing `JPanel`.

### View

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which I used to place four `JPanels`.  It's a good idea to create the `JFrame` and `JPanels` in separate methods or classes.  This helps keep the view code organized and makes the code easier to read and follow.

The `JFrame` creation methods **must be called in a specific order**.  The `run` method of the `JSliderExample` class has the order I use for most of my Swing `JFrames`.

I created four `JPanels`; the display `JPanel`, the drawing `JPanel`, and the two `JSlider` `JPanels`.  The drawing `JPanel` is a separate class.  The other three `JPanels` are methods in the main view class.

The display `JPanel` displays the circle center point and contains the `JComboBox` that allows the user to select a circle color.  The display `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` to place all the Swing components on one line.  The only "trick" I used was to add a `Box` horizontal strut (space) in between the circle center point and the color selection.  This makes the GUI look a little nicer.

The drawing `JPanel` extends `JPanel` and overrides the `paintComponent` method.  The `super.paintComponent` call must be first to maintain the Swing paint chain.  The `paintComponent` method draws the circle.

I invert the Y value so that the circle drawing corresponds with the Y `JSlider`.

The `JSlider` `JPanels` both use a `BorderLayout`.  I added a `JLabel` and added tick marks and values to the `JSliders`.  I start the `JSliders` at zero so the labels are round numbers, even though the code keeps you from selecting values outside the drawing `JPanel`.

### Controller

I created a `ChangeListener` for each of the `JSliders` and an `ActionListener` for the `JComboBox`.  I also created a `ComponentListener` for the `JFrame`.  Because I created an application model, these Swing listeners turned out to be fairly simple.

The `ChangeListeners` test for the slider moving and wait until the slider stops to redraw the circle.

I get the actual size of the drawing `JPanel` in the `JFrame` `ComponentListener` and save it in the model.  This allows the user to maximize and minimize the GUI, as well as change the size of the GUI.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class JSliderExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JSliderExample());
    }

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private final JSliderExampleModel model;

    private JComboBox<ColorModel> colorComboBox;

    private final JPanel xSliderPanel, ySliderPanel;

    private JSlider xSlider, ySlider;

    private JTextField xField, yField;

    public JSliderExample() {
        this.model = new JSliderExampleModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        this.xSliderPanel = createHorizontalSliderPanel();
        this.ySliderPanel = createVerticalSliderPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSlider Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
                Dimension drawingAreaDimension = drawingPanel.getSize();
                model.setDrawingAreaDimension(drawingAreaDimension);
                updateSliders();
            }
        });

        frame.add(createDisplayPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(xSliderPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(ySliderPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createDisplayPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Center point:");
        panel.add(label);

        label = new JLabel("x:");
        panel.add(label);

        xField = new JTextField(5);
        xField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(xField);

        label = new JLabel("y:");
        panel.add(label);

        yField = new JTextField(5);
        yField.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(yField);

        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

        label = new JLabel("Color:");
        panel.add(label);

        colorComboBox = new JComboBox<>(model.getColors());
        colorComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        colorComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                model.setCircleColor(
                        (ColorModel) colorComboBox.getSelectedItem());
                repaint();
            }
        });
        panel.add(colorComboBox);

        updateDisplayPanel();

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createHorizontalSliderPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Center x value");
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        xSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, d.width, p.x);
        xSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
                if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int x = (int) source.getValue();
                    updateCenterX(source, x);
                }
            }
        });
        xSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
        xSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        xSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        xSlider.setPaintLabels(true);

        panel.add(xSlider, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createVerticalSliderPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Center y value");
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        ySlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, d.height, p.y);
        ySlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
                JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
                if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int y = (int) source.getValue();
                    updateCenterY(source, y);
                }
            }
        });
        ySlider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
        ySlider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        ySlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        ySlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        panel.add(ySlider, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    public void updateDisplayPanel() {
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        xField.setText(String.format("%,d", p.x));
        yField.setText(String.format("%,d", p.y));
    }

    public void updateSliders() {
        Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        xSlider.setMaximum(d.width);
        ySlider.setMaximum(d.height);

        xSliderPanel.revalidate();
        xSliderPanel.repaint();
        ySliderPanel.revalidate();
        ySliderPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void updateCenterX(JSlider source, int x) {
        Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        int radius = model.getRadius();

        x = Math.max(radius, x);
        x = Math.min(d.width - radius, x);
        source.setValue(x);

        model.setCenterPoint(new Point(x, p.y));
        updateDisplayPanel();
        repaint();
    }

    private void updateCenterY(JSlider source, int y) {
        Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
        Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
        int radius = model.getRadius();

        y = Math.max(radius, y);
        y = Math.min(d.height - radius, y);
        source.setValue(y);

        model.setCenterPoint(new Point(p.x, y));
        updateDisplayPanel();
        repaint();
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final JSliderExampleModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(JSliderExampleModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingAreaDimension());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            ColorModel colorModel = model.getCircleColor();
            g.setColor(colorModel.getColor());
            Dimension d = model.getDrawingAreaDimension();
            Point p = model.getCenterPoint();
            int radius = model.getRadius();
            int diameter = radius + radius;
            g.fillOval(p.x - radius, d.height - p.y - radius, diameter,
                    diameter);
        }

    }

    public class JSliderExampleModel {

        private final int radius;

        private ColorModel circleColor;

        private final ColorModel[] colors;

        private Dimension drawingAreaDimension;

        private Point centerPoint;

        public JSliderExampleModel() {
            this.drawingAreaDimension = new Dimension(400, 300);
            this.centerPoint = new Point(200, 150);
            this.radius = 32;

            this.colors = new ColorModel[4];
            this.colors[0] = new ColorModel("Blue", Color.blue);
            this.colors[1] = new ColorModel("Green", Color.green);
            this.colors[2] = new ColorModel("Red", Color.red);
            this.colors[3] = new ColorModel("Yellow", Color.yellow);
            this.circleColor = colors[0];
        }

        public ColorModel getCircleColor() {
            return circleColor;
        }

        public void setCircleColor(ColorModel circleColor) {
            this.circleColor = circleColor;
        }

        public Dimension getDrawingAreaDimension() {
            return drawingAreaDimension;
        }

        public void setDrawingAreaDimension(Dimension drawingAreaDimension) {
            this.drawingAreaDimension = drawingAreaDimension;
        }

        public Point getCenterPoint() {
            return centerPoint;
        }

        public void setCenterPoint(Point centerPoint) {
            this.centerPoint = centerPoint;
        }

        public ColorModel[] getColors() {
            return colors;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

    }

    public class ColorModel {

        private final Color color;

        private final String colorName;

        public ColorModel(String colorName, Color color) {
            this.colorName = colorName;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public String getColorName() {
            return colorName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return colorName;
        }

    }

}
```